# How do I know if a list item has been viewed by the user?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a news feed, and I'd like to know when the user saw a post.
I am using this code.

```
      final int[] lastItemSeen = {0};
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            try {
                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);

                int lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);


                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + 1)) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null){
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                }
                if (lastVisibleItem != lastItemSeen[0]){
                    lastItemSeen[0] = lastVisibleItem;
                    timer[0].cancel();
                    timer[0] = new Timer();
                    timer[0].schedule(
                            new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    String objectId = getObjectId(lastVisibleItem);
                                    if (!isSeen(objectId)){
                                        seenObjects.add(objectId);
                                        Log.i("infoViewdtwae", "Item Add " + getObjectId(lastVisibleItem));
                                    }
                                    Log.i("infoViewdtwae", "this item was seen : " + getObjectId(lastVisibleItem));
                                }
                            },
                            DELAY
                    );
                }

            }catch ( Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

In parts, this code works fine. The biggest problem here is when I have an item that is larger than it fits on the user's screen, and when there is more than one item visible, this code does not work properly, since whenever a new View appears on screen, it cancels the timer and start counting again. I am thinking of improving this method but I do not know if it is the best option, do you have any suggestions or examples of codes to share with me? Thank you